# Мониторинг изменений и действий коллег в GitLab + VScode (win11)

Tags: javascript, php, git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

Всем привет! У меня 4 проекта и 4 репа на Гитлаб, с репами и проектами работаю в VScode.

Подскажите пожалуйста способ или решение, или плагин, единое окно, где я мог бы отслеживать все изменения во всех файлах проекта.

Нужны комментарии, коммиты, пушы\пуллы, удаления, добавления, МР и тд.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ¿Может тут имелось ввиду во всех файлах всех проектов? С файлами одного проекта гит и из коробки справляется.